# How can I hover the helicopter forward and backward?

Tags: aerodynamics, lift

[image]

I have a old toy helicopter which is currently not working. It has coaxial blades in order to lift it. It has a fixed shaft. Both blades have separate motor which helps them to rotate. I have very little knowledge about this field but while doing my research on this i found on Radio-controlled helicopter (wikipedia) that "Most models are fixed-pitch, i.e. the collective pitch of the blades cannot be controlled, plus the cyclic control is only applied to the lower rotor".

Is it possible that by increasing the speed of lower blade and simultaneously decreasing the speed of the upper blade i could make the helicopter move forward.
Please guide me.

Comment: Changing the relative speeds of the upper and lower rotors will cause it to yaw (rotate in place). Is there a cyclic control on one of the rotors? (There's something on the upper rotor.) That will tilt the whole thing forward or back. Other than that, as McGrew said, you need to use a weight.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the speeds of the blades should not cause the helicopter to move forward or backward.

You might be able to cause it to move forward or backward by shifting the center of gravity forward or backward: a small weight on a light stick might serve the purpose.